# Conversion of nested list to np.array for tensor model prediction is incorrect

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, keras, tensor

I have an input array created from :

```
initial window = 'I have a bad feeling about this'
seq_tokens = t.texts_to_sequences(initial_window)
# seq_tokens = [[4], [], [], [5], [590], [], [], [5], [], [998], [5], [], [], [], [], [], [], [4], [], [], [], [5], [998], [591], [], [], [], [], [], [4], []]
```

I need to reshape seq_tokens to (1, 7, 1). But when I do the following:

```
X_in = numpy.array(seq_tokens)
X_in = np.reshape(X_in, [1, 7, 1])
```

I get a messed up X_in like this:

```
[[[list([4])]
[list([])]
[list([])]
[list([5])]
[list([590])]
[list([])]
[list([])]
[list([5])]
[list([])]
[list([998])]
[list([5])]
[list([])]
[list([])]
[list([])] .........
```

I need to feed this to my GRU model. Which is throwing an error:

```
ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type list).
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this??

Comment: `seq_tokens` does not fit in a (1,7,1)-shaped array. Or am I missing something? What do you want the reshaped `seq_tokens` to look like?

Comment: I need it to be 3d array. But those missing value arrays are not getting added with hstack or asarray

Comment: You can't make a n-d array, or `tensor` from a mix of 1 element and 0 element lists.  Your lists need to be all the same length.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/text/Tokenizer#texts_to_sequences),  `Tokenizer.texts_to_sequences()` takes a list of strings as argument. If you provide a string only, it probably tries to create a list of sequences made up by single letters.

If I do a

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
import numpy as np
t = Tokenizer()
t.fit_on_texts([initial_window]) # I don't have your sequence tokens so I use what is provided
initial_window = 'I have a bad feeling about this'
seq_tokens = t.texts_to_sequences([initial_window])

#seq_tokens = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]]
```

Watch the square brackets around the texts to make them lists.